# How don't my double comparison work?

Tags: java, double

This is my code:

```
  System.out.println(templist.indexOf(8.14));
            if (ds > 8.1000 && ds<8.1500) {
                dot = templist.indexOf(8.14);
                dot++;
                System.out.println(dot);
            }
```

System.out.println(dot);

Here are the outputs:
1
0

why didn't dot get the value of 2? It's an int.

Comment: What is `ds`? Why do you expect a `2`?

Comment: for (double ds : templist)

Comment: I expect a 2 because I did dot++

Answer (score 0):

A result of:

```
-1
0
```

could have been explained if indexOf() failed to find the double value 8.14 in the list.

One suggestion is to make the below diagnostic changes to make sure the output you are seeing is indeed from the below code.

```
System.out.println("Before if-test = " + templist.indexOf(8.14));
if (ds > 8.1000 && ds < 8.1500) {
    dot = templist.indexOf(8.14);
    dot++;
    System.out.println("Dot = " + dot);
}
```

The above changes in the call to println() can be reverted back to your original code after you have identified the root cause.

Another possibility is to look at the class method implementations. If the object returned by the indexOf() method has a toString() method that converts a negative value to a positive value (e.g. toString() has been implemented to convert -1 to 1) then the toString() method will be invoked by the println() method. Whereas,

```
dot = templist.indexOf(8.14);
```

may be returning a -1. This could explain the output:

```
1
0
```

Hope this helps.
Thanks!

Comment: Hi @PeterWang, did the 2 possibilities indicated in my answer above help in resolving your issue? Thanks!